# Xcode 5 upgrade - Now nsobject.h has errors duplicate interface definition for class 'NSObject'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I upgraded to X-Code 5 last night. Now when I've gone to continue development on one of my iOS apps (which compiled fine on the previous Xcode version) I've hit an error I don't seem to be able to solve.

When I build the app I get a compile error:

```
duplicate interface definition for class 'NSObject'
```

This appears to actually occur in nsobject.h in both Foundation.Framework and UIKit.Framework.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I've removed and re-added both frameworks, performed several cleans, tried building it under several SDK's etc. None of which worked.

Any tips/Ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: Did my answer below help you? It has worked for me and several others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

verify that you do not have any old frameworks referenced in you *Framework Search Paths* under *Build Settings*. Remove those being old and update outdated locations.

Added a screenie for help. 
[image: screenie]

Comment: This helped me along. I removed and added all of the frameworks and I had to update one of them to a version for iOS7. This fixed my problems. Thanks!

Comment: @Adam:  i am also stuck in this problem , can you tell me how you removed & add all frameworks ?