# Matplotlib installation on Mavericks

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, installation, osx-mavericks

I'm having problem while installing `matplotlib`. I'm using Mavericks and it complains about a deprecated NumPy API both installing via `pip` and installing from source (following the instructions here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/README.osx):

```
In file included from src/_macosx.m:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:76:1: error: 
  duplicate interface definition for class 'NSObject'
@interface NSObject <NSObject> {
^
/usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:50:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface NSObject <NSObject> {
       ^
In file included from src/_macosx.m:5:
In file included from /Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/datascience/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/datascience/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:
In file included from /Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/datascience/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:
/Users/se7entyse7en/Envs/datascience/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: 
  "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API
  NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
 ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

After that it exists without having completed the installation. I have already installed both `libpng` and `freetype` using `brew`, and I also already have installed both `NumPy` and `SciPy` via `pip`:

```
numpy==1.8.2
scipy==0.14.0
```

Comment: you posted only the warning, and i wouldn't worry about that specific warning. please post the error

Comment: google is your friend. have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245741/xcode-5-upgrade-now-nsobject-h-has-errors-duplicate-interface-definition-for-c)?

Comment: @flebool and how can I fix this?

Comment: have you noticed that I posted you a LINK?

Comment: @flebool yes, I noticed it. I meant if you may elaborate a bit more the answer of that question as I do not understand how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue also thanks to flebool. In the folder

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

I had both `MacOSX10.9.sdk` and `MacOSX10.8.sdk` and I didn't know if they should exists both. I had Mavericks so I thought that maybe `MacOSX10.8.sdk` could be the problem. I deleted it and I managed to install `matplotlib` from source succesfully.